# Grouping ActiveRecord objects and outputting to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I am wondering how I can make this work.  Assuming I have a model of Project that belongs_to a Client.  I want to output those particular projects to JSON, but they need to be grouped by their client.  I thought this would work:

```
@projects.group_by(&:client).to_json
```

That ALMOST works, except the to_json method isn't calling .to_json on the client, so for the client you get this in your JSON:

```
"#<Client:0x1051d4fb0>":[{ "project":{"name":"My Only Project", "client_id":1}}]
```

But I really need it like this:

```
{"client":{"name":"Home Workers Unite", "id":1, "projects":[{"name":"My Only Project","client_id":1}]}}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The "json" that you want is not valid. -- Property names must be strings.

Comment: I'm not writing JSON and what I put in there was just me trying to trim what was being output from Rails.  I just can't believe this isn't easier and part of the Rails core.

Comment: ps. Hashes are not ordered. So you can't have an ordered hash. Hashes contain zero or more pairs of property names and values.

Comment: Larry, Rails has a special class for ordered hashes.

Comment: Cool, I stand corrected. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already told by @LarryK, the json you want as out put is not a valid json. In json keys can only be strings unlike ruby which can has objects as keys. Also, I would suggest that the json response be more like following:

```
{clients: [
    {
      "name":"Home Workers Unite", 
      "id":1,
      "projects": [
        {"name":"My First Project", "id":1},
        {"name":"My Second Project", "id":2}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You already have projects available with you. You also have the code to group them by client, but a simple `to_json` on the resulting hash would not be suitable here. You would need to manipulate the grouped response further to be able to directly use `to_json`:

```
results = {clients: []}
@projects.group_by(&:client).each do |client, projects|
  results[:clients] << {
    id: client.id,
    name: client.name
    projects: projects
  } 
end
results.to_json
```

This is ruby/rails version of the solution. However if you have a json heavy application, I would suggest using some gem([jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), or any other) to create the desired responses.

PS: code is not tested

Comment: @rubish i took your advice of using rabl, would you mind helping me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660136/include-group-by-parent-model-json-rabl

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at the gem **acts_as_api**.
It makes it very easy to manipulate your objects as JSON.

Comment: It looks good for the straight-forward stuff, but I don't see how it would work in my case.  For example, because I don't want to include all projects, its not a simple parent/child template.

Comment: Well, with this gem you can create separate scopes for each case you want. It's really simple to use and it is very very good.
For example you can create a template client json that includes the child processes with a template that only shows one or two attributes. It's pretty customisable.

Answer (score 0):

The json in your orig post is not valid json since you don't have a property name for the array of projects.

Look into the acts_as_api suggestion from Murifox and other api techniques from railscasts--he just did one recently.

If your api user only wants one client at a time, you can use a json structure such as:

```
{client: {"name":"Home Workers Unite", "id":1},
 projects: [
      {"name":"My Only Project", "client_id":1}
           ]
}
```

Or you can send a subset (or all) of the needed client and project info:

```
{clients: [
   {"name":"Home Workers Unite", "id":1},
   {"name":"Factory Workers Unite", "id":2},
          ],
 projects: [
      {"name":"My Only Project", "client_id":1},
      {"name":"Project 2", "client_id":2},
      {"name":"Project 3", "client_id":2}
           ]
}
```

Benefit: fewer roundtrips from the server to the api client.